# what is the difference between pip install panda & pip install pandas. please note that one is without an S

Tags: python, pandas, pip

I'm running on Windows 10 and I accidentally typed into the command prompt:

```
pip install panda
```

I'm afraid the above line could've downloaded and installed something malicious onto my PC.

Please note that the official command for Pandas is with an "S":

```
pip install pandas
```

P.S: @Python community, please remove "Panda" library as this is a very common mistake. Please let "pip install panda" return an error msg like, library not found.

Comment: just had a look at the pypi package and source code and there seems to be nothing malicious about the package - I think it wouldn't make it ways onto pypi otherwise (althought I could be wrong) it seems to be a python rest package. see more [here](https://pypi.org/project/panda/0.3.1/#files)

Comment: Just done the same as @Manakin above, looks like it's a package relating to video processing. Just run `pip uninstall panda` to remove the package you've installed by mistake and try to be more careful in future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference is you are installing two different things from PyPI (official package manager for python):

The first one according to PyPI description is "A Python implementation of the Panda REST interface" which belongs to this https://www.telestream.net/telestream-cloud/overview.htm company. so don't worry it's not something malicious. And I don't think it's something illegal to have a name similar to other packages.

and

The second one according to PyPI description "Powerful data structures for data analysis, time series, and statistics" which is the famous Pandas package that everyone uses for data manipulation purposes.

Answer (score 2):

There is an online video encoding service called [telestream](https://www.telestream.net/telestream-cloud/overview.htm) which has an API called Panda. The Python package called [panda](https://github.com/pandastream/panda_client_python) provides an interface to this API. Thus, I don't think it is a virus nor is it a specific mistake that needs removing from PyPI.